# New metrics for health of a site

Tags: discussion, feature-request, metrics

I love the stats currently used to [rank the sites](https://stackexchange.com/sites?expand=true). But as the network grows I wonder if some additional metrics might be employed.

1. **Total Reputation** - the cumulative reputation by all users of a specific site.
2. **Gross Site Product (GSP)** - The amount of reputation created in a set period of time; day, week, month, etc.

Over time these metrics would show how a site is growing or contracting. In essence how healthy it is.

**Unit of Reputation**, It might be necessary — as we will be talking about large amounts of rep — to invent a unit. I suggest the **Skeet** (Sk); 1Sk = 250,000 rep.